# How to upload a java file which manipulates files to a webserver?

Tags: java, upload, filesystems, webserver

I have a java program which uses streams to read and write files. I want to upload it to a web server, but i fear that if two people simultaneously use my website, and when these users upload their file in my web server, how do i differentiate both their files, how do i make separate environment to different users, do i have to give them a job id or process id.

Comment: What do you mean by "upload it to a webserver"? What environment will it be running in?

Comment: There are big differences between java-program for the console compared to java-programm for a web server. I think you should start with simple web-app examples to learn from and try to integrate the code from your existing java programm into the web application.

Comment: You need to create unique names or paths on sever for all the differnet files being uploaded.

Comment: How is console based java program different than java programming for web server, do i have create an applet like application?

Comment: Congratulations, you have just entered the exciting and rich world of Java web programming. Please read the Oracle Java EE tutorial, especially the part [The Web Tier](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/partwebtier.htm#BNADP). Have fun ;-)